# Determining whether a set is Vector Space or Not

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

Q: Determine whether the set $V = \{(x,\,y):x\ge 0,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ with the standard operations in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is a vector space.

A:For the each $u\in V$ there exists a $-u\in V$. If we apply this rule to our $V$, we see that it does not apply.

My question is, is the answer I have given above is a correct, applicable one?

Comment: For future reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You recieved 4 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try to be clear by giving an example.

$(1,0) \in V$ because $1\ge 0$ and $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. However $-(1,0)=(-1,0) \notin V$ since $-1<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it suffices just to exhibit a counter example which doesn’t satisfy the definition that is

$$v=(1,y)\in V$$

but $-v \not \in V$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, but the execution needs work. How do you know the rule does not apply?

Remember: if you are saying that the statement "for all $u$, *this thing* is true", is false, you need to show that the statement "there exists some $u$ for which *this thing* is false" is true.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer, thought in a bit more formal manner you can say, that some elements of $V$ doesn't have an additive inverse, and hence it's enought to give only a single counterexample.